# What is the best way to consume a web service in Grails?

Tags: web-services, grails, soap

I know there are a few web service plug-ins for Grails, some of them look like they aren't maintained. I have a jar with all the stubs generated from a wsdl and now I need to start integrating. Which plugin would serve best for this? Also, the web service uses SOAP, not REST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know your question asked about a plugin for consuming, but I've never used one of the Grails-WS plugins, so I can't comment there.  Instead, if your stubs are compatible with JAXB marshalling you can use the Spring Web Services project.  You'll just have to add a dependency in `BuildConfig.groovy` to import the appropriate jars.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/client.html

So you just define some JAXB marshaller/unmarshaller beans and web service handlers.  You can get as detailed as you want with this from the documentation above and define timeouts and security if you specify your own connection handler or interceptors.

```
myJaxb2Marshaller(org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller) {
    classesToBeBound = ['my.class.Class1','my.class.Class2']
}

myWebServiceMessageFactory(org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory)

myWebServiceTemplate(org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate, ref('myWebServiceMessageFactory')) {
    marshaller = ref('myJaxb2Marshaller')
    unmarshaller = ref('myJaxb2Marshaller')
}
```

At that point you can use Grail's dependency injection to use the `WebServiceTemplate` in your Grails code:

```
class myService {
    def myWebServiceTemplate

    void myMethod {
        ...
        Class1 myRequestObject = new Class1(data:myData)
        Class2 myResponseObject = myWebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(mySoapEndpoint, myRequestObject)
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Spring's way. 
You're developing in grails after all, so maybie you don't need a plugin.
Read Spring docs on [Remoting and webservices](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html), chapter 19.5.2 "Accessing web services using JAX-RPC".

No need for any of your jar's stubs. Spring will generate everything for you...

P.S. : I assume you know how to declare spring beans in grails...

Comment: The web service uses over 100 WSDLs, I'd rather not define each one in Spring... this really seems cumbersome..